# Help proving the equivalence of lower semicontinuity and sequential lower semicontinuity involving the negation of a stament with multiple quantifiers

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, calculus-of-variations, quantifiers

Let $X$ be a metric space, $G:X \to \mathbb{R}$ a functional

Def 1) $G$ is slsc(sequentially lower semicontinuos) at $x$ $\Longleftrightarrow$ $G(x) \leq \liminf_{x_n\rightarrow x} G(x_n)$ $\forall x_n \rightarrow x$ in $X$.

Def 2) $G$ is lsc(lower semicontinuos) if for every $x \in X $and every $t \in \mathbb{R}$ with
$G(x ) > t$, there exists $r > 0$ such that $G(y) > t$ for all $y ∈ B(x , r )$;

**I wanto prove that they are equivalent**

To prove $1) \implies 2)$ I argue by contradiction.

Suppose 1) holds and 2) is false. 2) being false means that its negation is true.
First I rewrite 2) in a more clear way, specifying the quantificators and moving them to the begining of the sentence I think the statement has an if-then structure:

Def 2') $G$ is lsc(lower semicontinuos) if  $\forall x \in X $, $\forall t \in \mathbb{R}$, $\exists r > 0$: $\forall y ∈ B(x , r )$, if $G(x ) > t \implies G(y) > t $

**So the negation should be**

$G$ is NOT lsc(lower semicontinuos) if  $\exists x \in X $, $\exists t \in \mathbb{R}$, $\forall r > 0$: $\exists y ∈ B(x , r )$,  $G(x ) > t$ and $G(y) \le t $

and I chain up these last two inequalities together with that from the hypothesis of slsc:

$\forall x_n \rightarrow x$ in $X$,
$G(y) \le t<G(x) \leq \liminf_{x_n\rightarrow x} G(x_n)$

**1) From here I don't know how to continue. In particular, am I correctly negating the statement ?I am a bit unsure if it was ok to move the quantifiers around as I did**

**2) How do I prove $2) \implies 1)$?**

Comment: The negation of 2) is logically correct. Assuming that 2) is false (i.e. its negation is true), try to prove that 1) is false by building a sequence $x_n\to x$ such that $\liminf G(x_n) < G(x)$.

Comment: @Gribouillis isn't it the existence of such a sequence assumed as hypothesis? I mean I have $\forall x_n\to x$, meaning I fix one such sequence assuming there is one, otherwise I am clueless about how to build an specific one

Comment: It depends on what you want to prove. When you want to prove 1), you need to prove something for any arbitrary fixed sequence $x_n\to x$, but if you want to prove the negation of 1), it starts with $\exists x_n\to x$..., so you only need to build a particular sequence. As  I said, try to prove that $\neg 2)\Rightarrow\neg 1)$.

Comment: @Gribouillis
 Wouldn't it suffice to say that since $x_n$ is converging to $ x$, eventually for sufficiently large $n$, all the elements of the sequence are in a Ball of fixed radius? and therefore$G(x_n)\le t$, from which$t< \liminf_{x_n\rightarrow x} G(x_n)\le t$ ?

Comment: Otherwise following your suggestion I can take radii $1/n, n\in \mathbb{N}$ and choose a $y_n$ for each corresponding radius, so that $d(x,y_n)<r$, where $d$ is the metric, but then I wouldn't know how to continue

Comment: That's right, assuming $\neg 2)$, you can choose $y_n\in B(x, 1/n)$ such that $G(y_n)\le t$. You are now very close to proving $\neg 1)$

Comment: what if in  $G(y_n)\le t <G(x)$, I take the liminf?, I would have$ \liminf G(y_n)\le t <G(x)$, but I wanted instead $ \liminf G(x_n)\le t <G(x)$, how do I fix that?

Comment: @ Gribouillis See my answer above. By the way, wasn't the first reasoning correct (Wouldn't it suffice to say that since ......)?

Answer (score 0):

For $ t \in  \mathbb{R}$, let $ {S}_{t} = {G}^{{-1}} \left(\left(t , \infty \right)\right)$.
We can rephrase your question's properties 1) and 2) as
$\ $

1. For every $ t  <  G \left(x\right)$ and every sequence
   $ {x}_{n} \rightarrow  x$, one has $ t  \leqslant  {\liminf }_{n} G \left({x}_{n}\right)$
2. For every $ t  <  G \left(x\right)$, there is a $ r  >  0$
   such that $B \left(x , r\right) \subset  {S}_{t}$

**Proof that 2) $\Longrightarrow $ 1)**

Suppose 2), let $ t  <  G \left(x\right)$ and $ {x}_{n} \rightarrow  x$. Choose
$ r$ as in 2). For $ n$ large enough, one has
$ {x}_{n} \in  B \left(x , r\right)$, hence
$ t  <  G \left({x}_{n}\right)$.
By taking the limit inf, it follows that $ t  \leqslant  {\liminf }_{n} G \left({x}_{n}\right)$.

**Proof that 1) $\Longrightarrow $ 2)**

We use the following property: for every $ x \in  X$ and every set $ S \subset  X$, exactly one of the two properties holds
$\ $

- a) There is a $ r  >  0$ such that $B \left(x , r\right) \subset  S$
- b) There is a sequence  $ {x}_{n} \rightarrow  x$ such that $ \forall  n , {x}_{n} \notin  S$

Indeed case a) means that $x \in  \text{int} \left(S\right)$ and case b)
means that $ x \in  \text{cl} \left(X \setminus  S\right)$, but it is well
known that the complement of the interior is the closure of the
complement.

Now, suppose that 2) is false, let $t  <  t' < G \left(x\right)$ such that a) doesn't
hold for $ {S}_{t}$. By b) one can find a sequence
$ {x}_{n} \rightarrow  x$ such that $ {x}_{n} \notin  {S}_{t}$, that is to say $ G \left({x}_{n}\right)  \leqslant  t$. It follows that
$ {\liminf }_{n} G({x}_{n})  \leqslant  t  <  t'$ and 1) is false for $t'$.